# reuse ElementListSelectionDialog on Eclipse 4 RCP Application

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have a basic implementation of ElementListSelectionDialog, like following.

```
ElementListSelectionDialog dialog = 
  new ElementListSelectionDialog(shell, new LabelProvider());
dialog.setElements(new String[] { "Linux", "Mac", "Windows" });
dialog.setTitle("Which operating system are you using");
dialog.open();
```

The dialog opens well, but the list is empty, and when we type something in the search field, nothing happens.

I don't have any exception, I am under Eclipse Kepeler 4.3

I read somewhere that the selection dialog are directly reusable after 4.2 release of eclipse.

I deeply examined the ElementListSelectionDialog class, and I found that the problem comes from FiltredList not draw the elements provided via LabelProvider.

```
FilteredList list = new FilteredList(workArea,SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL,new LabelProvider(),false,true,true);
     list.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL,
            GridData.BEGINNING, true, false, 1, 1));
list.setFilter(""); //$NON-NLS-1$       
list.setElements( new Object[] {"Item 1","Item 2","Item 3","Item"});
```

I don't know why it does not work for me, but one thing I am sure of is that it works fine in the Eclipse IDE.

I think I have no alternative, I must define my own Dialog based on a TableViewer

Has anyone succeeded to run a ElementListSelectionDialog in Eclipse 4 because it would be a shame not to use it, it's a Dialog to use as standrad

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. Dialog updates it content via TableUpdateJob. Method `schedule` contains check against `PlatformUI.isWorkbenchRunning()`. So ever if you have custom RCP application you must start Workbench anyway or emulate this behavior.